# Got weird fullscreen ad when visiting website

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, ads

When I vistit on my nexus one the website alternativeto.net and open a subpage then suddenly I see a fullscreen ad with the title "liferay.com" and the address cat.m.ifortune.mobivillage.de

I see the desktop version of alternativeto.net when I visit them

Is it a problem of alternativeto.net or is there some virus on my smartphone?

It doesnt happen on other websites while surfing with my smartphone

**if it is not android related, please move it to the right board (didnt know if i should post it in superusers?)**

Comment: some sites do that, ads are revenue, if it's really annoying you then root your device and install an adblock app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be related to the website. It's possibly just a pop-up ad.

Currently there's no known virus for the Android platform. There're other forms of malware but no viruses. Nevertheless you should always make sure to only install applications from trusted sources.